# Angular Websocket connection wss://localhost/ng-cli-ws' failed:

Tags: angular, websocket

I am running my Angular application from a VirtualBox VM that is port-forwarding so I only have to type localhost into my browser.

Unfortunately I am getting this error and the browser does not refresh on changes. Is there any way I can work around this?

This is what appears when I run ng serve, but I only need to go to localhost.

```
 Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/
```